# React API call GET request in use headers x-api-key. cosole.log net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs

Could you please explain me there is my mistake ? Thank you very much.

key component.

```
export const API_KEY = "MY_KEY"

export const PrefixUrl = "MY_URL"
```

I turing to make API call. Here is my code.

```
import "./App.css";
import ky from 'ky';
import {API_KEY} from "./components/key";
import {PrefixUrl} from "./components/key";

async function getAllData(event) {
    try {
        const todos = await ky.get(PrefixUrl,{
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers:{
                accept: 'application/json',
                'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
            }
        }).json()
    console.log(todos)
    } catch (err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

function App () {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Hej</h1>
        <button onClick={getAllData}>Get data</button>
    </div>
)
}

export default App
```

console.log

```
bundle.js:41878     (*************MY_URL*************)  net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)
```

P.S.
The URL and key are correct.

Comment: What is `import ky from 'ky';` ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ky I want to use it in future. async function getAllData(event) = async function getAllData() my small mistake. But anyway........ same